# How to compare two snaps from same table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

Greetings for the day!

I am pretty new to oracle, wanted to know how can i compare London 12:00, 31st Jan 2022 rates with London 11:0 rates, 31st Jan 2022 for all the maturities. currently, i have joined two select queries using union but not able to think what all joins i should use to get the desired result. is it possible to add a new column as MID_rate2 that will represent rates for London 11:0 against Mid_rate representing London 12:00 and then an additional column of difference?

```
SELECT i.name, vyc.rowkey, vyc.timezone, vyc.asof, vyc.snaptime, (vp.rate) mid, vp.bid, vp.ask
                FROM val_yield_curves vyc
                JOIN val_yc_def_elements el ON el.pkey=valuations_yieldcurves.getCurveDefinitionKey(vyc.asof, vyc.object_id)
                JOIN (SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_interestrates
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_basisswaps
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_oisrates
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_fx
                ) vp ON el.instrument = vp.instrument AND vp.asof=vyc.asof AND vp.curve=vyc.rowkey
                 JOIN (select pkey, symbol from val_mds_sources) vms on vms.pkey=vp.source
                 join instruments i on  i.pkey = el.instrument
                WHERE vyc.asof in '31Jan2022'
                  --and vyc.asof <= '26JAN2011'
                AND vyc.timezone in 'L1200'
                and vyc.object_id like '%SGD_OISSwap_T%'
                --order by vp.updatetime
                
UNION

SELECT i.name, vyc.rowkey, vyc.timezone, vyc.asof, vyc.snaptime, (vp.rate) mid, vp.bid, vp.ask
                FROM val_yield_curves vyc
                JOIN val_yc_def_elements el ON el.pkey=valuations_yieldcurves.getCurveDefinitionKey(vyc.asof, vyc.object_id)
                JOIN (SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_interestrates
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_basisswaps
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_oisrates
                UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_fx
                ) vp ON el.instrument = vp.instrument AND vp.asof=vyc.asof AND vp.curve=vyc.rowkey
                 JOIN (select pkey, symbol from val_mds_sources) vms on vms.pkey=vp.source
                 join instruments i on  i.pkey = el.instrument
                WHERE vyc.asof in '31Jan2022'
                  --and vyc.asof <= '26JAN2011'
                AND vyc.timezone in 'L1100'
                and vyc.object_id like '%SGD_OISSwap_T%';
                --order by vp.updatetime;
```

[image]

Comment: HI , did you try using the MINUS and seeing the differance between the data generated by the queries, may be that could work for you ?

Comment: MINUS parameter is only returning those rows which are unique

Comment: HI, you can try PIVOT, can you please give us some simple example  data and how you want the output.